# Create Popup window in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need help on this JavaScript and jQuery.

In my Grid.js file

```
template: `"<div>#if(data.SiteCount > 0){#<a href = 'javascript:void(0);' onClick='showDiv(#:Id#)'>#:Count# Sites</a>#} else{#test#}#</div>",`
```

my grid.cshtml page:

```html
    <div class="grid-content-area">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.Partial("~/V.cshtml")
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn-common">Create Template</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="Grid"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/RequestModule/Grid.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have a template like above.

My `showDiv` function like below

```
function showDiv(data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert(data);
}
```

Now inside this function, I need to get data from URL: "/example.mvc/test/data" and want it to popup when clicked.

My pop up code will be like:

```html
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Comment: @romellem i am asking for way to implementation as I do not know how to do it .Please give me any example if possible like link .i was unable to find any exact